# If $Y$ is deterministic then $P[X=x, Y=y]=P[X=x]$

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $P[Y=y]=1$ and $X$ has positive variance. How would you show that $P[X=x\mid Y=y] = P[X=x]$?

By Bayes' rule this is the same as showing $P[X=x,Y=y]=P[X=x]$

I think $P[\{\omega\in\Omega :\ X(\omega)=x \text{ and }Y(\omega)=y\}]+P[\{\omega\in\Omega :\ X(\omega)=x \text{ and }Y(\omega)\ne y\}]
=
 P[\{\omega\in\Omega :\ X(\omega)=x \}]$

and notice that in the LHS the second term is less than $P[\{\omega\in\Omega :\ Y(\omega)\ne y\}]=0$, therefore it is zero.

But I don't know if this is convincing.

Answer (score 1):

For any event $A$ with $\mathsf{P}(A)=1$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(B\cap A)=\mathsf{P}(B)
$$
because
$$
\mathsf{P}(B^c)\le \mathsf{P}(B^c\cup A^c)\le \mathsf{P}(B^c)+\mathsf{P}(A^c)=\mathsf{P}(B^c).
$$